# regex to validate input value should be greater than 0 (1 or 0.123)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a text input in which I need to make sure that users can only enter a value which is greater than 0. For example if user enters 0.123 then it will pass but if the user enters 0.00 or 0 than fail.

Comment: How about `>` instead of a regex?

Answer (score 0):

Why whould you need a regex ?

In order to check the validity on the input you can use `>` operator. To prevent floats, your input can be of type "number":

```
<input name="xx" type="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex, it will not match only integers greater than zero:

> /\d*[1-9]\d*